# Tween Animation is not working in Custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I make tween animation in Custom View. so I create "MyView Extend view" and 
"Sprite Extend ImageView". And I make 'Sprite ' instance in Myview, and call sprite.onDraw() 
Method in Myview.onDraw() Method. But... tween animation is not working.... 
Just image is seen. Help me. I don`t understand.

Here is the Source Code.
Activity.

```
public class Myview01Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Animation MainRotate;
Myview myview;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MainRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Myview01Activity.this, R.anim.rotate);
    myview = new Myview(Myview01Activity.this);
    setContentView(myview);
    Log.i("TAG", "Come in");
}
```

}

Myview.

```
class Myview extends View {
Sprite sprite;
public Myview(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    sprite = new Sprite(context);
    Log.i("TAG", "Come in");
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onDraw(canvas);
    sprite.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Sprite

```
class Sprite extends ImageView {
Bitmap bitmap;
Paint paint;
RotateAnimation rotate;
Animation myanimation;
AlphaAnimation blend;
ScaleAnimation scale;
AnimationSet spriteAnimation;
float centerX;
float centerY;
float offsetX;
float offsetY;

public Sprite(Context context) {
    super(context);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    offsetX = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
    offsetY = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (spriteAnimation == null) {
        centerX = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
        centerY = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
        createAnimation(canvas);
        Log.i("TAG", "Come in");
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, centerX - offsetX, centerY - offsetY, paint);
}

public void createAnimation(final Canvas canvas) {
    rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, centerX, centerY);
    rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    scale = new ScaleAnimation(0, 2, 0, 2, centerX, centerY);
    scale.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    scale.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    scale.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

    spriteAnimation = new AnimationSet(false);
    spriteAnimation.addAnimation(rotate);
    spriteAnimation.addAnimation(scale);
    spriteAnimation.setDuration(3000);
    startAnimation(spriteAnimation);

}
```

Comment: why u have created my view.directly use sprite and also u have not applied animation on view to play.See my answer and try it.

Answer (score 0):

take an instance variable like this

```
Sprite view;
```

and inside on create do something like this:

```
 MainRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Myview01Activity.this, R.anim.rotate);
    view = new Sprite(this);
    setContentView(view);
    view.startAnimation(MainRotate);
    Log.i("TAG", "Come in");
```

Try it.It may work.

Comment: yes, Your Comment is Right. But I`d Like to make Custom View, like that background of 'MyCustom View' has rotate & translate tween animation. And When i touch the Screen, i`d want to make 'Circle' that have scale & alpha tween animation. So i make two custom view(MyView & Sprite) in upper source. This is impossible thing?

Comment: Anybody don`t know this problem? ,,,